# Key Error when trying to get header value

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am just trying to request a form value in flask. Something i have done many times before with no issue but I cannot figure out why I am getting this key error.

I have tried many things like switching from a get request to a post request but nothing seems to be working.

App Route:

```
@app.route('/Exercise', methods = ['GET'])
def exercise():
    test = request.form["title"]
    print(test)
    if test != None:
        info = select(["*"],"Exercises",["Name"],"And",[test])
        print(info)
    return render_template('exercise.html')
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<form>
  <h2 class="head" id="name" name="title"></h2>
  <p class="lead">Details</p>
</form>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/exercise.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think it matters as you should be able to request most values in a form. I did try this already tho and still the key error persists.

Comment: The form is not filled out by a user a js function gives it the value. If you can't get a non submitted form value from I'm not sure how i can get this value.

Comment: you can use an input tag with the `hidden` type

Comment: Changing to an input tag doesn't stop the key error tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so thanks to PRMoureu I discovered I needed to make the called url contain the field I wanted to get with flask. Example below:
window.location.href = "/Exercise?title="+name;

Thanks for the help 
much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Since you're supporting the `GET` method only try accessing your `title` key like so:

`request.args.get('title')`

instead of `test = request.form["title"]` as this is the way you would access the `title` key in a `POST` method.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: I have tried request.args.get('title') but when i print test it prints none even though there is a value there